# How does ASP.NET Identity 2.0 handle the scenario where some hacker creates thousands of bogus accounts

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

In this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx) it says: "Email Confirmation is useful because it prevents bogus accounts from being created.". But if I look at the code a user account always gets created prior to the email confirmation process.

Say if some hacker registers thousands of bogus users; how does ASP.NET Identity 2.0 handle this?

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            // THE USER ALWAYS GETS CREATED HERE:
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The wording in that post is not quite correct.  Its up to the app to decide what to do with unconfirmed users.  For example, the app could run some kind of background task which purges unconfirmed users after 30 days or the like.

Comment: Okey, I thought that the framework had some built-in function(s) for this - sounds like it from that sentence in that article. Perhaps add some info regarding that to the article/ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Samples for clarification. The background task is a good idea btw.

Comment: How can I achieve the "unconfirmed users after 30 days" as I don't find and create time stamp in the model? Should I manually add this extra fields? It sound me too much stupid? Where is my mistake?

Comment: You have to manually add the timestamps for CreationDate if you want to do something like this